# Dynamically update label text in kivy program (Python)

Tags: python, dynamic, kivy

New to the kivy library and having some trouble dynamically updating a property.  The label here is just a place-holder.  Ultimately I want the displayed image to change sequentially based on which quadrant the user clicks/touches.

The program runs fine with no errors, hover the label (label2) does not update (label1 does update).  When I click on the four quadrants the quadrant number is displayed to the console as I would expect.  I'm also printing out the self.incr whenever the user clicks on Q1 and this also displays and increases which means the incr attribute is increasing as it should.

So, I can't figure out why it doesn't update for the label.

main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.image import Image

class TouchInput(Widget):

    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        self.incr = 5
        super(TouchInput,self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def on_touch_up(self, touch):

        if touch.x < self.width / 2:
            lateral = 'left'
        elif touch.x > self.width / 2:
            lateral = 'right'
        else:
            lateral = None

        if touch.y < self.height / 2:
            vertical = 'bottom'
        elif touch.y > self.height / 2:
            vertical = 'top'
        else:
            vertical = None

        if vertical and lateral:
            if lateral == 'left' and vertical == 'top':
                quadrant = 1
                print 'Q1'
                self.incr += 1
                print self.incr
            elif lateral == 'right' and vertical == 'top':
                quadrant = 2
                print 'Q2'
            elif lateral == 'left' and vertical == 'bottom':
                quadrant = 3
                print 'Q3'
            elif lateral == 'right' and vertical == 'bottom':
                quadrant = 4
                print 'Q4'

class PPVT(App):

    def build(self):
        t = TouchInput()
        print t.incr
        return t


if __name__ == "__main__":
    PPVT().run()
```

main.kv

```
<TouchInput>:
    Image:
        source: 'img1.jpg'
        size: root.width, root.height
    Label:
        id: label1
        text: str(root.width)
        pos: root.width / 2, root.height / 2
    Label:
        id: label2
        text: str(root.incr)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a numeric property, so kivy can track its changes.

```
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty
...
class TouchInput(Widget):

    incr = NumericProperty(5)
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks, that works well.  I'm curious why I can't set an attribute with self.attr and have kivy keep track when it does keep track of things like self.width?

Comment: @Daniel `self.width` is a property, probably also a numeric property.